# Main sound device disappears in "jack" plug

Tags: sound, devices

I have a laptop with "jack" audio output. When I plug my headphones in, I expect to have two sound device - main laptop speaker and headphones, any of which I can select in my settings. But the "speaker" sound device disappears. Can I have two devices?

Ubuntu version is 22.04.

Comment: What happens when you unplug the headphones? It would also be a good idea to add the version of Ubuntu to the question with the edit command.

Comment: I have single speaker device again. To be precise, "Speaker - Family 17h HD Audio controller".

Comment: That may be how your hardware works, it turns off one when you plug in the other. Some do work that way. Still waiting for the version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I guess no, because Windows on the same laptop accepts both devices and switches with software between ones. (I updated the version in the question, it is 22.04)

Comment: You should also add what you said about it works in Windows. Any help you get is as good as the info provided.

Comment: Try pulseaudio volume control `sudo apt install pavucontrol`

Comment: If anyone is interested, I reinstalled my Ubunti with xubuntu+cinnabon, and its "Volume Control" can swich it.